# How to mask the images in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, linux

I have MODIS NDVI images, which needs to be masked with VI_Quality. I am using GRASS software and executing GRASS commands using shell scripts. I need to perform raster calculation (multiplication) for NDVI images with the VI_Quality. I want to multiply ith NDVI image with the ith image of VI_Quality. I have used the following codes :

```
for file in $NDVIFILES;
do
r.mapcalc "$file = $NDVIFILES * $QAFILES;
done

i=1
for file in $NDVIFILES;
do
r.mapcalc "file $((i++)) = NDVIFILES $((i++)) * QAFILES $((i++))";
done
```

I am unable to do this raster multiplication in a loop. Please let me know the correct syntax to do this operation.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some clarifications: What do you get if you type: echo $NDVIFILES ? What about: echo $QAFILES ? And what do you get if you run, for example: sed -n "3p" $NDVIFILES ?

Comment: NDVIFILES=$(g.mlist -p type=rast pattern=*NDVI mapset=shenkottah); QAFILES=$(g.mlist -p type=rast pattern=Qu* mapset=shenkottah); So when I use the command echo $NDVIFILES, I get the following o/p: rast files available in mapset <shenkottah>: A2013001h25v08NDVI A2013097h25v08NDVI A2013193h25v08NDVI A2013289h25v08NDVI A2013017h25v08NDVI A2013113h25v08NDVI A2013209h25v08NDVI A2013305h25v08NDVI; Similarly I get o/p for echo $QAFILES; sed -n "3p" $NDVIFILES is not working. Please let me know if I need to clear anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I suggest:

```
g.mlist --q type=rast pattern-"*NDVI" mapset=shenkottah >> NDVIFILES
```

and a similar expression for the QAFILES
This will leave you with two files on your disk, each containing a list of the raster map names. To verify, test with the sed expression:

```
sed -n "4p" NDVIFILES
```

Then you should be able to run a loop to read the raster names and do your mapcalc, something like:

```
for i in `seq 1 22`; do \
NDVI=`sed -n "${i}p" NDVIFILES`;
QA=`sed -n "${i}p" QAFILES`;
r.mapcalc new_${i} = $NDVI * $QA;
done
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Micha! This code worked!! --With regards, Karthik K.